# import from specific branch github in the same repository where it is hosted

Tags: go

I have a repository with a Go project in Github, I need to import in a module a specific branch, to make relevant modifications. It looks like this:

```golang
import (
    "github.com/repository/utils/date_utils"
    "github.com/repository/utils/utils/error_utils"
    "github.com/repository/utils/utils/hour_utils"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)
```

The import is always done directly from the master. I just need this module to import from a different branch.

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
go get <path-to-repo>@<branch>
```

From [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go@master#hdr-Add_dependencies_to_current_module_and_install_them)

> Get resolves its command-line arguments to packages at specific module
> versions, updates go.mod to require those versions, downloads source
> code into the module cache, then builds and installs the named
> packages

Also this particular line on the [documentation](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#how-to-upgrade-and-downgrade-dependencies) is interesting as-well.

> Using a branch name such as go get foo@master (foo@default with mercurial) is one way to obtain the latest commit regardless of whether or not it has a semver tag.

Comment: Can I mod directly from de repository? de go.mod an then the module? I can´t use a command line. I'm sorry I'm new using go